# I have a bug when hovering over one element to change another element's style

Tags: html, hover

Here is my jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/greyshark7/9kwAZ/

I have two divs, represented as red box and a green box. I wrote code so that when the red box is hovered over, the green div becomes larger, and vice versa.

```
/*make red box bigger when user hovers over green box*/
.greenbox:hover + .redbox{
    width:200px;
}

/*make green box bigger when user hovers over red box*/
.redbox:hover + .greenbox{
    width:200px;
}
```

However it only works when I hover over the red box. When i hover over the green box, nothing happens.

I can't see why it doesn't work, especially since I literally copied the working code and simply changed "red" to "green" and vice versa.

Answer (score 0):

This is because `+` selector selects all elements that are placed immediately after first element. Second selector does not work because there is no `.redbox` element after `.greenbox`.

Comment: Ok, I think I see. So it's dependant on the order of the elements in the html? It would explain this: http://jsfiddle.net/greyshark7/3vX6c/

Comment: Exactly. You can not select and modify element that precedes hovered element because there is no appropriate selector for that. I guess you will have to use some Javascript then...